# Unable to create prisma schema

Tags: reactjs, prisma

I am trying to create a new prisma project by `npx prisma init` and it shows the error that `` The default query engine type (Node-API, "library") is currently not supported for 32bit Node. Please set `engineType = "binary"` in the "generator" block of your "schema.prisma" file (or use the environment variables "PRISMA_CLIENT_ENGINE_TYPE=binary" and/or "PRISMA_CLI_QUERY_ENGINE_TYPE=binary".) ``. Can anyone give some possible solutions to solve the problem?

I followed thoroughly the steps in the documentation and it got stuck

Answer (score 0):

You have installed NodeJS for 32-bit system. If you are using a 32-bit system then try updating/adding this to your `schema.prisma` file:

```
generator client {
  provider   = "prisma-client-js"
  engineType = "binary"
}
```

or, set the Env variable: `PRISMA_CLIENT_ENGINE_TYPE=binary` before prisma init.

If you got 64-bit system, re-install the latest stable NodeJS 64-bit and it should work.